# How do I get a 1.5 V reference voltage from a 3 V coin cell battery?

Tags: voltage, analog, low-power, instrumentation-amplifier, voltage-reference

My goal is to build an amplification circuit powered by a 3 V coin cell battery that uses an instrumentation amplifier to read a differential voltage.

The instrumentation amplifier chip has a reference pin that I wish to set to 1.5 V.

How do I get a constant 1.5 V voltage reference from the 3 V battery?

Comment: @JYelton: this question is about getting a steady 1.5 V for a *reference pin*, so perhaps not a duplicate of the mentioned question.

Comment: If it's a precise *reference voltage* you are looking for, and not a power rail, you could use a 1.5 V voltage reference IC.  

It seems there are few 1.5 V voltage references out there (other voltages are more common), but the [ISL2101](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/dst/isl21010-datasheet) series has one.

Comment: There are billions of fixed and adjustible micropower "voltage reference" chips on the market... I suggest using a common adjustible reference and setting the output voltage with 1% or 0.5% resistors, such as an LM4041-ADJ. However, since you're using a coin cell, battery life can be a problem. LM4041-ADJ has an operating current in the range of 100 μA, which may not be good enough. In this case it makes sense to find a more expensive model. Just search the web.

Comment: Instead of a 3V cell, you could perhaps use 2 pieces of 1.5V silver oxide cells.  These are remarkably stable voltage outputs over lifetime (hence why they're used in wristwatches).  You can get your 1.5V reference by simply tapping the center of your series cells.  You wouldn't want to draw any significant current from the center tap, as it would cause one cell to age faster than the other. But a voltage reference is generally a very very high input impedance so it'd probably be OK.   (Only you can determine that...)

Comment: @ocrdu Perhaps. In my answer to that question, I do mention linear regulators as well as resistor dividers, either of which might be useful in this context. As written, I felt it was vague enough to warrant pointing to a list of methodologies, which might lead OP to the terminology they seek.

Comment: how do I evaluate if a voltage reference IC or a low drop regulator is a better solution here? Thanks for the tips